# SQL - Return dates for 2 or 3 weeks intervals (before and after) based on a datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to specify a date (2020-01-20) and then return every 2 weeks forward and backwards between a start and finish period. So 01 Jan 2020 to 01 Mar 2020 for example. A list of of all the dates every 2 weeks from this input date.

Sample of table data for reference...

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE(bookingcode int, NextWeekCommDate DATETIME, Cycle int)
insert into @Source (bookingcode, NextWeekCommDate, cycle)
select 556789, '23 Mar 2020', 2
insert into @Source (bookingcode, NextWeekCommDate, cycle)
select 556790, '30 Mar 2020', 3
select * from @Source

declare @from datetime = '01 Mar 2020'
declare @to datetime = '01 Jun 2020'
```

Then I am trying to output the following results based on the declared@to and @from dates

```
bookingcode     CycleOccurDate
556789          2020-03-09 00:00:00.000
556789          2020-03-23 00:00:00.000
556789          2020-04-06 00:00:00.000
556789          2020-04-20 00:00:00.000
556789          2020-05-04 00:00:00.000
556789          2020-05-18 00:00:00.000
556790          2020-03-30 00:00:00.000
556790          2020-04-20 00:00:00.000
556790          2020-05-11 00:00:00.000
```

So it works backwards as well from the NextWeekCommDate if the @from date is before this Thank you again

Comment: Yes, many. What have you tried, why didn't it work? What research did you perform, otherwise, and what about it didn't you understand? if not,  I suggest looking at a Tally and `DATEADD` or a Calendar Table. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with dates as (
      select convert(date, '2020-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(week, 2, dte)
      from cte
      where dte < '2020-03-01'
     )
select *
from dates;
```

If this can return more than 100 rows, then use `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

It is not clear to me what `'2020-01-20'` has to do with the question.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I believe this is close to working, I have added a snippet of script to create a table with a demo of the fields I am working with and the output trying to achieve. I cannot quite get it to work with your script. Thank you for your support and help

Comment: Thank you I got this working as my understanding of CTE recursive was lacking. So I correctly added the anchor and passed in the from and to dates from a temporary table. This enabled me to use that as the terminator to the string. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can add directly or substract fom a date field

```
SELECT GETDATE(), GETDATE()-14, GETDATE()+14
```

or in date

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE()-14 AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE()+14 AS DATE)
```

Take a look at DATE FUNCTIONS in SQLSERVER, there are plenty of them that you may use 
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you, I need it to go further. So for example it would return all the dates in 2 week cycles, so for example. If the '09-03-2020' was specified then 23-03-2020 and 06-04-2020 and 20-04-2020 and 04-05-2020 would appear and so on.....This jumping of dates would be dependant on a booking cycle int such as 2 or 3 which decides if it needs to return 2 or 3 week intervals. Dates could range as much as over next 6 months

Comment: Then you need to program this behaviour, I see no way to do it programatically with a SELECT statement due to its variability.